# Java - Waiting for some type of key press to continue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

What is the best way to implement a "press x to continue" type of thing in Java?

Specifically, I have a custom class which extends JFrame and a custom class which extends JPanel. I have a Main.java (which has an instance of my JFrame class), and there is a point where I do not want to continue until the user has pressed the space bar:

Main.java:

```
...code...
frame.waitForSpace();
...more code which gets executed only after space is pressed...
```

So, in my frame class, how should I implement this:

MyFrame.java:

```
/* This method only finishes when the space bar is pressed */
public void waitForSpace() {

}
```

By the way, I have the KeyListener on my JFrame which works when the space button is pressed. But I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that into what I'm trying to do.

Example code would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **CountDownLatch** when await() is invoked, the current main() thread will wait until the countDown() method is called from another thread.

The **KeyEventDispatcher** lets you add a keystroke listener globally.  So whenever a key is pressed dispatchKeyEvent() gets called from the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) and there you can check for 'space' being pressed and release the countdown latch that main() is waiting on.

However, if the thread that calls waitForSpace() is the EDT, then you will be forcing the EDT to wait for itself, causing **deadlock**.  It is impossible to wait on the EDT and still receive key events as far as I know.

This will work so long as a JFrame has focus:

```
public void waitForSpace() {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        // Anonymous class invoked from EDT
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                latch.countDown();
            return false;
        }
    };
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
    latch.await();  // current thread waits here until countDown() is called
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
}
```

Comment: would you mind elobrating on this? i've never done something like this before. where would this code go?

Comment: does this only register once if the space bar is typed? it seems to be registering more than once.

Comment: every time the method is called a new KeyEventDispatcher will be added to the listeners, but after space is pressed it will be removed.

Comment: but if I hold space, multiple events are fired. how do I make this so that it's based on space typed, not space pressed?

Comment: specifically, if you add a print statement above the "latch.countDown" and then you press space, it will print twice

Comment: A count down latch is used when you wish to wait for multiple worker threads to complete which is not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: check if e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED

Comment: Although this is a nice way of doing things, as @Gnon says, it doesn't work in what's probably the most common case: where the code that wants to wait is itself running on the event thread.

Answer (score 2):

Put whatever you want to do when the user presses space into that handler. Most likely you don't want to do (whatever) every time the space bar is pressed, but only some of the time; therefore the event handler should be contingent on the value of some variable, and the code that runs *before* you want the user to press space should set that variable to the value that means "do it." The handler should set the variable back to the the default value after it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Swing GUI's are event driven. So don't wait for anything. Instead give your class a state field of some sort, perhaps a boolean, change the state variable on key press, perhaps using key bindings, and then don't allow certain behaviors unless the state has been changed (via if statements).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyLIstener.

Use Key Bindings. You've already been given a link to the key bindings tutorial.